# Renavigating to current route in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So there seems to be an established pattern when it comes to authentication and transitioning.

On transition check authentication -> session expired -> stored attempted transition -> redirect to login -> successful login -> retry attempted transition

This we have already implemented and it works fine. Now we are wondering what to do when an action contains for example a rest call where authentication fails due to expired session? Here we want to redirect to login as with transitioning but the question is how do we get to where we were in the application before? Storing the routeName is not enough as there may be dynamic segments. Is there any ember object in the background that stores the current route including url parameters?

Comment: Maybe you could always store the latest transition from the application route's `willTransition` action and use that where necessary?

Comment: The question is can I store a transition that was completed and reuse it at a later date. From the guide" abort the transition by calling transition.abort(), and if the transition object is stored, it can be re-attempted at a later time by calling transition.retry(). ". I will play around it, but I thought someone might have a running solution.

Comment: It's a bit clearer. The long term storages in Ember called service. It is a simple object, which lives the duration of the application. You can store and reload from there anything what you need between the transitions.

Comment: I think I may have made it incorrectly clear :) because that's not what I meant. We do use services for long term storage. As below: "The question is what do you save in order to re-transition to any given route. Sure I can access the routeName, but what if there are dynamic segments?"

Comment: Well, the transition object itself contains the dynamic segments, and query parameters too. Just take a closer look at the transition properties. And if just the transition matters, save the transition and a simple transition.retry() will give you what you want. In some case you need to add the retry function call to a run loop. If you have a form data, or some component state, then you need to save those too.

Comment: Based on the [not so easy to find source code](https://github.com/tildeio/router.js/blob/master/lib/router/transition.js) of the `Transition` object, and following the trail of breadcrumbs, I don't immediately see anything standing out that would stop you from `retry`ing a previously stored and already-completed `transition`. Of course, trying it out will give you your definite answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so to celebrate the fact I found the `Transition` [source code](https://github.com/tildeio/router.js/blob/master/lib/router/transition.js) that I remember previously searching for as well, I went ahead and tested this for you in an Ember application I'm working on. The short and sweet of it is that **yes, you can `retry()` a stored transition at any time** and as such my suggestion is to always store the latest transition, and then `retry` it when necessary in your session expiration case. Well, latest useful transition anyway, your transition to the login route etc. should of course be ignored.

You may even be able to use a similar relatively quick arrangement as I did just now. In my application route, `routes/application.js`, I added the following action handlers

```
actions: {
    willTransition: function(transition) {
        this.set('_latestTransition', transition);
    },
    saveTransition: function() {
        var transition = this.get('_latestTransition');
        console.log('transition saved', transition);
        this.set('_transitionSnapshot', transition);
    },
    retryTransition: function() {
        var transition = this.get('_transitionSnapshot');
        console.log('transition retry', transition);
        transition.retry();
    }
}
```

Then, for my test, I just added two buttons in an always-visible menu: one to trigger the `saveTransition` action and the other the `retryTransition` action. The result was, as I already spoiled, that after clicking my save button, doing several other transitions afterwards, and then clicking the retry button, I ended back at the page I was when first clicking the save button. The dynamic segments were fine; I don't have query params in use anywhere so testing those wasn't quick enough for me to bother, but the `Transition` object apparently does hold those as well.

Since these action handlers reside in the application route, as long as nothing else in the app handles actions by those names (or especially in the `willTransition` case the actions get bubbled by returning `true`), they will get dealt with here. As said, you may be able to use this approach yourself, or store the necessary transition using some service intermediary as per your needs and as suggested in comments.

Comment: Ok thanks! I had actually started looking at the code too, but hadn't gotten around to testing it. I may ask a question on the ember boards to see if it is ok to do this. I don't want the functionality to stop working on a minor version upgrade or something.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/) guide. Especially the "Storing and Retrying a Transition" part what you need.

**Edit:**

If you looking for a session service implementation take a look at [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/addon/services/session.js)'s session service.

Comment: I was aware of the guide: that is what the transition retry mechanism in my question is based on. In my case there is no transition happening only an action from for example a button click.

Comment: Ok, I am not sure I understand correctly. But if you have an action (button click), you have an action handler too. And there you can check if the session is valid. If the session is invalid save anything you need (to a service or to a property) and you can create a transition to the login page. And after the user restored the session (logged in again), create a new transition and load what you need from that service.

Comment: Sure: that's what I do in a number of places. The question is what do you save in order to re-transition to any given route. Sure I can access the routeName, but what if there are dynamic segments?

Comment: It really depends on your implementation. What do you need to save in order to retry the transition? The route name? The dynamic segments? The component's current state (for example a form data what the user typed so far)? You can save anything to a service. And you can load those data from the service after the session is restored, and create a transition and set up a component regarding the stored data.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using ember-simple-auth. In this case, try to add following code in your application route:

```
actions: {
    error: function (error, transition) {
        /**
         * Handle 401 error during model hook
         */
        if (error.errors !== undefined) {
            for (var i = 0; i < error.errors.length; i++) {
                if (error.errors[i].status !== undefined) {
                    if (parseInt(error.errors[i].status) === 401) {
                        transition.abort();
                        this.set('session.attemptedTransition', transition);
                        this.transitionTo('login');
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

This important line `this.set('session.attemptedTransition', transition);` I took from [authenticated-route-mixin](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/addon/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin.js).

Comment: We're not using simple-auth but the transition mechanism we have is very similar to the above. The case I am asking about is when no transition is in play, rather a 401 from a rest call in an action. It would be good to have a similar behaviour here.